# X11: Tracking process writing to or reading from clipboard

Tags: clipboard, x11, pid

Is there any way to track the process(get PID), which is writing to or reading from X11 clipboard ?

Comment: What distro? Window manager? Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu with gdm. I tried something like tracking the selection events, getting window id and then from window id to the process id. But that idea was not working.

Comment: why that idea didn't work? I think this is the right approach